# Error when processing Pay later contribution

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, paylater

Using Drupal 7.44 and CiviCRM 4.7.8.

When using CiviCRM 4.6.18 a Pending (Pay Later) contribution can be completed by editing the Membership that it relates to, checking the box 'Update Payment Status' and completing the payment. When this is done in a copy of the (upgraded) database in version 4.7.8 an error is displayed 'Please enter the financial type'.

This is almost certainly an error of the database upgrade or the application itself.

Comment: Hi Martin,

After looking on my dev site running 4.9 and on the JIRA demo site, I do not see a box that says "Update Payment Status" - what I am able to do (according to our usual process for pending pay later contributions) is edit the associated contribution and change the contribution status to completed - upon saving the contribution, the membership status is also updated accordingly without any error indicating that the selection of a financial type is needed - perhaps if you could provide a screen shot it would help to determine whether this issue is a bug or not?

Comment: This seems really strange. What you say is correct: it is only necessary to set the Pay Later contribution to completed and everything flows from that. However I am absolutely certain that at some point in time there was a separate 'Update Payment Status' checkbox. I can only conclude that I must have been drinking!

Answer (score 2):

I'm relatively new to CiviCRM and realize this is an old thread, but I just got the same error on Wordpress 4.7.4 and CiviCRM 4.7.15. I was trying to record a update a membership based on a cash payment. Screen shot below shows the error received. I unchecked "Update Payment Status" and was able to save and continue. I had to add a new contribution for this person after saving the the membership changes.

[image: Update Payment Status Error]

Comment: Welcome PaulR! Since this question is quite old, I suggest you repost this as a new question and include a link to this one.  You might want to try upgrading - there continues to be quite a lot of development activity around contributions and this may have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Glad I could help - regarding "Update Payment Status" - there is an action that allows you to "Update pending contribution status", but I don't recall seeing a check box anywhere - if you do happen to see it again (assuming you are not drinking), send a screen shot.

Thanks!